# Does npm mssql supports authentication type azure-active-directory-access-token to connect to azure sql server

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-authentication, tedious, node-mssql

I have read that mssql module uses Tedious internally to connect to azure sql db. Hence i am trying to establish a connection using azure-active-directory-access-token. However, i am getting error as
ConnectionError: Login failed for user token-identified principal

Sample Code :-

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
const msrestAzure = require("ms-rest-azure");

const clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const serverName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const databaseName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const tenantId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
let token = 0;

msrestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId,
    clientSecret,
    tenantId,
    {
        tokenAudience: "https://database.windows.net/",
    },
).then((databaseCredentials) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        databaseCredentials.getToken((err, results) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(results.accessToken);
        });
    });
}).then((token) => {
    // console.log(token);
    var config = {
        server: serverName,
        authentication: {
            type: "azure-active-directory-access-token",
            options: {
                token: token,
            }
        },
        options: {
            database: databaseName,
            encrypt: true,
        }
    };
    return new mssql.connect(config);
}).then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool;
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: We do have very limited document on npm mssql supports authentication type azure-active-directory-access-token to connect to azure sql server so for now as workaround  Would suggest you to please add these details in config to login SQL server and try then to execute

Comment: var config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'XXX.XXX.X.XXX',
    driver: 'msnodesql',
    database: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    connectionString: "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=#{server}\\sql;Database=#{database};Uid=#{user};Pwd=#{password};"
};

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204411/connect-to-sql-server-with-mssql-for-node-js?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

There is way you can use it connect Azure SQL Server using Service Principal in NodeJS(NPM) authentication by azure-active-directory-access-token.

1.Create A service principal

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n 'MyApp' --skip-assignment
```

2.Configure SQL Database

a. [Use your Azure Sql AD admin to connect Azure SQL vai SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)

b. Add the service principal to the database you need use

```
create user [<Azure_AD_principal_name>] from external provider
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [<Azure_AD_principal_name>]
```

3.Code

```
 var msrestAzure = require("ms-rest-azure");
    var { Connection, Request } = require("tedious");
    
    let clientSecret = "xxx";
    let serverName = "xxx.database.windows.net";
    let databaseName = "xxx";
    let clientId = "xxx";
    let tenantId = "xxx";
    
    async function getConnect() {
      // way for Azure Service Principal
      let databaseCredentials = await msrestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        tenantId,
        {
          tokenAudience: "https://database.windows.net/",
        },
      );
    
      // getting access token
      let databaseAccessToken = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        databaseCredentials.getToken((err, results) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(results.accessToken);
        });
      });
      var config = {
        server: serverName,
        authentication: {
          type: "azure-active-directory-access-token",
          options: {
            token: databaseAccessToken,
          },
        },
        options: {
          debug: {
            packet: true,
            data: true,
            payload: true,
            token: false,
            log: true,
          },
          database: databaseName,
          encrypt: true,
        },
      };
    
      var connection = new Connection(config);
      connection.connect();
      connection.on("connect", function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        executeStatement(connection);
      });
    
      connection.on("debug", function (text) {
        console.log(text);
      });
    }
    function executeStatement(connection) {
      request = new Request("select * from CSVTest", function (err, rowCount) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(rowCount + " rows");
        }
    
        connection.close();
      });
    
      request.on("row", function (columns) {
        columns.forEach(function (column) {
          if (column.value === null) {
            console.log("NULL");
          } else {
            console.log(column.value);
          }
        });
      });
    
      request.on("done", function (rowCount, more) {
        console.log(rowCount + " rows returned");
      });
    
      connection.execSql(request);
    }
    
    getConnect()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("run successfully");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Reference : [Connecting to Azure SQL using Service Principal in NodeJS, but token is rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436022/connecting-to-azure-sql-using-service-principal-in-nodejs-but-token-is-rejected)